# Not getting 0th position of recyclerview in on bindview holder

Tags: android

**here is my code**
my adapter class

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder myviewholder,  int i) {
        final String userid=userModulList.get( i ).getUid();
        final String username=userModulList.get( i ).getName();
        String userabout=userModulList.get( i ).getAbout();
        String userImage=userModulList.get( i ).getImage();

        myviewholder.namelist.setText( username );
        myviewholder.listabout.setText( userabout );
        try {
            Picasso.get().load( userImage )
                    .placeholder( R.drawable.images )
                    .into( myviewholder.mlistimage );
        }catch (Exception e){

            myviewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent( context, chatmassage.class );
                    intent.putExtra( "hisuide",userid );
                    context.startActivity( intent );
                    Toast.makeText( context, ""+username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            } );

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userModulList.size();
    }

    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CircleImageView mlistimage;
    TextView listabout,namelist;
    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super( itemView );
            mlistimage = itemView.findViewById( R.id.Rawiav );
            namelist = itemView.findViewById( R.id.Row_name );
            listabout = itemView.findViewById( R.id.Row_about );
```

class

```
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
        recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.user_List );
        muserdatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "users" );


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager( this ) ;
        linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );


        userModulList = new ArrayList<>();
        getAllUaer();
    }

        private void getAllUaer () {
            final FirebaseUser fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "users" );
            ref.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    userModulList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        UserModul modul = ds.getValue( UserModul.class );
                        if (!modul.getUid().equals( fuser.getUid() )) {

                            userModulList.add( modul );
                        }
                        adpteruser = new Adpteruser( all_user.this, userModulList );
                        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter( adpteruser );
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );


    }
```

please help  to how to get zero 'th position
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V5Pt.png please see the pic 
so my error is that when i am click on first item it dose response but after clicking on second or third and so on position it work so how did i solve it please help mi

Answer (score 1):

In your code you set click listener for item in **catch** clause. So If image not getting load and goes in catch block then that item get click listener.

**Solution:**

Remove **itemView.setOnClickListener** from catch clause and put that either in your **ViewHolder** or **outside try catch block**